# Generate random 6 digit number

Tags: c#

I've been searching for a couple of hours and I just can't seem to find a answer to this question. I want to generate a random number with 6 digits. Some of you might tell me to use this code:

```
        Random generator = new Random();
        int r = generator.Next(100000, 1000000);
```

But that limits my 6 digits to all be above 100 000 in value. I want to be able to generate a int with 000 001, 000 002 etc. I later want to convert this integer to a string.

Comment: `001` is not an integer...`1` is an integer, `001` can only be a string.

Comment: But they are not 6 digits?

Comment: That's a display problem. generate 1->999999 and then FORMAT it as a zero-padded string.

Comment: If you want to turn "1" into "000001" you need to use myNumber.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0').  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ye, sorry about that. I later want to convert this int to a string... edited my text just now. Is there any solution?

Comment: that's not a random number only, is a number filled with zeros, try to implement a string.format over the returned random number

Comment: @DavidStratton - or just `myNumberToString("D6")`

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Yeah, or what Matten suggested.  Now I'm wondering if all that complies to the same MSIL.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If you want a string to lead with zeroes, try this.  You cannot get an int like 001.

```
    Random generator = new Random();
    String r = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");
```

Comment: this also generate 5 digit sometime

Answer (score 27):

You want to have a string:

```
Random r = new Random();
var x = r.Next(0, 1000000);
string s = x.ToString("000000");
```

For example,

```
x = "2124"
s = "002124"
```

Comment: Please can you tell me whether the Random class needs to be disposed?

Comment: Random does not implement IDisposable, therefore no need to dispose it manually or use it inside a using statement.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in a comment, a "six digit number" is a string. Here's how you generate a number from 0-999999, then format it like "000482":

```
Random r = new Random();
int randNum = r.Next(1000000);
string sixDigitNumber = randNum.ToString("D6");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
private static string _numbers = "0123456789";
Random random = new Random();


private void DoWork()
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(6);
   string numberAsString = "";
   int numberAsNumber = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
      builder.Append(_numbers[random.Next(0, _numbers.Length)]);
   }

   numberAsString = builder.ToString();
   numberAsNumber = int.Parse(numberAsString);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a better solution, because it gives you more random numbers and is not based on the system clock.

> Cryptographic random number generators create cryptographically strong random values.

```cs
System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(0, 1000000);
```

To ensure that the resulting value has six digits, you can convert to string and append zeros at the start. e.g `GeneratedValue.ToString().Padleft(6,'0')` using Matt's method above.

See [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-6.0) for additional details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");
```

or

```
string s = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("000000");
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment above that 000 001 can't be an integer, but can be a string with:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int r = generator.Next(1, 1000000);
string s = r.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
```

Comment: Upper bound is exclusive

Answer (score 0):

solutions that use

```
Random generator = new Random();
int r = generator.Next(1, 1000000);
```

dont seem to work always.
I am calling the following method in a class constructor and it gives same number after the first time.

```
        internal string GenerateID()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int randNum = r.Next(1000000);
            string sixDigitNumber = randNum.ToString("D6");
            return sixDigitNumber;
        }
```

Attached is image of the debug statement in .net unitTest for the class.
My project is .net 4.8.

I have moved to using `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` as suggested above.

[image]