# How to generate 4 digit numbers randomly?

Tags: c#

I am using this piece of code:

```
byte[] intBytes = new byte[4];

rnd.GetBytes(intBytes);

return Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(intBytes, 0)) % maxValue + 1;
```

The above code only generates `3` digits. I would like for it to generate `4` digits?

I have changed the `byte[4]` to `byte[5]` but still only generates `3` digits?

Comment: what are you interpreting as "digits" here? do zeros count? if it was me, I'd have just done `rand.Next(0, 10000)` - and just left-padded with zeros... is it just the left-padding that is the real problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique 4 digit random number in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749543/unique-4-digit-random-number-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If `rnd` is of type `Random` and *4 digit numbers* means *number in [1000..9999] range* then `int result = rnd.Next(1000, 10000);`. If *4 digit numbers* means `[0..9999]` range then  `int result = rnd.Next(10000);`

Comment: What type is `rnd`? System.Random class does not have that method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random 6 digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208413/generate-random-6-digit-number)

Comment: check this SO answer, solves exactly your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749592/10617111

Answer (score -1):

What about?

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(1000, 10000);
```

Comment: `random.Next(1000, 10000);` - please, note that upper bound is *exlusive*