# Generate 7 digit unique, random and unpredictable string (include 0-9 number) in c#

Tags: c#, random

I want to generate 7 digit unique, random and unpredictable string include 0-9 number for each new record saved into my database, I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22208515/1890313) solution but I'm still wonder about how can I be sure that the string are not duplicated in the database?

Should I compare each new one with the all others saved in database or there's a better solution?

If I want to print an ID card for each registered user, This ID card contain the 7 digit random number, I don't want this number to be sequential to avoid every one know how much people that registered, Also I don't want the number to be predictable,

The best example is the passport number, It's unique, random and unpredictable contain numbers and characters. I used the Guid as an identity but I can't used it to print it on ID card.

Comment: GUID identity is not an option?

Comment: Did you consider to use an incremental counter in the database?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you

Comment: @mm8 I want random number not sequence number

Comment: @Magnetron I edit the question, Please check it.

Comment: What's your use-case for wanting a specific random number and not a sequence/guid?

Comment: Do you also want this string to be unpredictable, so that someone having the unique code of one record to not be able to predict the unique code of the next record, even if they know the implementation of the code generator?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, That is what I want

Comment: In that case be aware that a seven-chars code consisting of a 36 letters alphabet (26 latin letters + 10 digits), makes for a total of 78,364,164,096 unique combinations. Cryptographically it's not very secure. Someone hitting your database via a web interface 1000 times per second, would scan the whole range in about 3 years.

Comment: The number's is public use, I want just to be sure that it's not duplicated

Comment: If you require uniqueness then go sequentially.

Comment: Abdulsalam if the unique strings are for public use, and it's OK for anyone knowing anyone else's code, then why the requirement of being unpredictable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way to do it is generate a List from 1 to 9999999, then remove the itens already added to the database. Finally, use a random from 0 to the length of the list to get an item from it, add the item to database and remove from the list. Something like this:

```
//this is for the example, should be replaced by your database
var myDatabaseValues = new List<string>()
{
    "0000000",
    "9999999",
    "1234567"
};
//Put in a place where Random get initialized only once.
Random rdn = new Random();
//Generates all possibilites
var fullList = Enumerable.Range(0,10000000).ToList();
//Remove the itens already present in the DB.
foreach(var val in myDatabaseValues)
{
    int num = int.Parse(val);
    fullList.Remove(num);
}

//Then, to get a new number
var nextNum = rdn.Next(0,fullList.Count);
myDatabaseValues.Add(nextNum.ToString("D7"));
fullList.Remove(nextNum);
```

Just make sure you are the only one wirting to the database, or query the DB evertytime.

Based on your comment that you don't want it to be predictable, you shouldn't use the Random class, but a cryptographic safe class.

Based on your new comments, I think the best way will be pre-populate a table with all the possibilities already shuffled, and when you need a new id you pick it from the table and remove it. Something like this:

```
//Pre populate, should be done only once
//this is for the example, should be replaced by your database, ideally with a auto-increment first column so you can sort by it when you pick it.
var myDatabaseValues = new List<string>();

Random rdn = new Random();
//Generates all possibilites, and shufle it
var fullList = Enumerable.Range(0,10000000).OrderBy(x=>rdn.Next()).ToList();

foreach(var num in fullList){   
    myDatabaseValues.Add(num.ToString("D7"));   
}


//Now, when you need a item from db, pick one and remove it. 
//Just be sure to lock the table so multiple accesses don't read the same value at the same time
var nextVal = myDatabaseValues.First();
myDatabaseValues.Remove(nextVal);
//use the nextVal as you want
```

Comment: I expect the database will contain about 6,000,000 recorded, Search every time adding a new record won't cause slowdown?

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif yes it would. But again, that's 60% of your number space (7 digits), so why do you need it to be random? There is a high chance anyone would guess a number that is present in the database. If your describe better in your question what are you trying to achieve, instead of how you're trying to do it, we could provide better answers. Like, why can't you use a Guid, or a sequencial number?

Comment: I want to print a ID card for each registered user, This ID card contain the 7 digit random number, I don't want this number to be sequential to avoid every one know how much people registered, The best example is the passport number, It's unique and random and contain numbers and characters. I used the Guid as an identity but I cant used it to print it on ID card.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question.

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif You could pre-generate the list and shufle it, and then store the list in the database. When you need a new item, you pick and remove it from the DB. That way the heavy work will only be to create the initial list.

Comment: I really thank you and appreciate your help, I think this is the right way to accomplish what I want, by using this senario there will be no delay, just pick a one from the shilf. Please add this in an answer to accept that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have several conflicting goals: You want identifiers that are unique, random, hard to guess, and easy to type by end users. But other things you should think about are:

- Are other users allowed to access the resource identified by the ID, whenever they know the ID? If not, then **additional access control or a longer ID length** will be necessary. This is because otherwise, an attacker could probe your application for IDs and thus gain access to resources they shouldn't access. Note that in your case of 7-digit IDs, there are only 10 million possible IDs, which can be easy to guess; an attacker would only need a relatively small number of guesses to find a match — all the more so if your IDs are sequentially assigned or generated using a weak random number generator such as C#'s `System.Random`.
- It appears you can't tolerate the risk of duplicate IDs. Thus, you will need to check new IDs against existing ones. There are many ways to do so, however, and they depend greatly on the application and infrastructure.

See also my [section on unique random identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers) as well as: [How can I generate a unique, small, random, and user-friendly key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708/how-can-I-generate-a-unique-small-random-and-user-friendly-key)