# Django/Python generate and unique Gift-card-code from UUID

Tags: python, django, uuid

I'm using Django and into a my model I'm using UUID v4 as primary key.

I'm using this UUID to generate a Qrcode used for a sort of giftcard.

Now the customer requests to have also a giftcard code using **10 characters** to have a possibility to acquire the giftcard using the Qrcode (using the current version based on the UUID) as also the possibility to inter manually the giftcard code (to digit 10 just characters).

Now I need to found a way to generate this gift code. Obviously this code most be unique.

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@parker.cattell.atkins/unique-gift-coupon-code-generation-with-django-bf8f46ee3b9f) where the author suggest to use the auto-generaed id (integer id) into the generate code (for example at the end of a random string). I'm not sure for this because I have only 10 characters: for long id basically I will fire some of available characters just to concatenate this unique section.

For example, if my id is 609234 I will have `{random-string with length 4} + 609234`.

And also, I don't like this solution because I think it's not very sure, It's better to have a completely random code. There is a sort regular-format from malicious user point of view.

Do you know a way to generate an unique random string  using, for example from an input unique key (in my case the UUIDv4)?

Otherwise, do you know some algorithm/approach to generate voucher codes?

Comment: What about appending the auto-generated ID onto the back of your UUID? 

`{uuid}-{auto-generated-id}`

From a security perspective this is still pretty secure, as the UUID is still random, but it also allows you (or your customer) to be able to easily find out what the ID is of the gift card.

Comment: @wKavey the UUID is 32 characters long, adding other characters it will be even longer but I can use, in totally, only 10 characters...

Comment: You and your customer should consider that with 10 decimal digits, there are 10^10 possible codes, and the chance of "hitting" an assigned code (by random probing) becomes non-negligible after 100,000 codes are generated (and perhaps sooner than that if you assign some of the digits as "check digits" to detect typing mistakes). For additional considerations, see my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666404/generate-7-digit-unique-random-and-unpredictable-string-include-0-9-number-in/64667872#64667872).

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import secrets

unique_digits = string.digits
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(unique_digits) for i in range(6))

print(password)
```

The above code pallet generates a unique code of integers for the number of digits you want. In the above case, it will print a 6-digit unique Integer code.
If it doesn't let me know, what exactly you want.